# Windows BATCH CMD: To automatically replace line in config file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use a batch file to automatically replace a particular line within a configuration file. Managed to find sample code from the stack overflow forums.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the configuration file as the configuration file contains special operator characters such as "<" ">"  "[" "]" etc.

Newbie here. Appreciate any help from experienced users.

```
@Echo OFF

:: TEXT MANIPULATOR ROUTINE v0.5
:: by Elektro H@cker

REM SYNTAX:
::
:: TEXTMAN [ACTION] [LINE(S)] [FILE] [TEXT]
::
:: * [LINE(S)] parameter is Optional for some actions
:: * [TEXT] parameter is Optional for some actions

REM ACTIONS:
::
::  AB  = ADD_BEGINNING      * Add text to the beginning of a line.
::  AE  = ADD_ENDING         * Add text to the end of a line.
::  E   = ERASE              * Delete a line.
::  I   = INSERT             * Add a empty line (Or a line with text).
::  RL  = REPLACE_LINE       * Replace a entire line.
::  RS  = REPLACE_STRING     * Replace word from line.
::  RSA = REPLACE_STRING_ALL * Replace word from all lines.
::  C+  = CHARACTER_PLUS     * Delete the first "X" characters from all lines.
::  C-  = CHARACTER_LESS     * Delete the last  "X" characters from all lines.
::  L+  = LINE_PLUS          * Cut the first "X" amount of lines.
::  L-  = LINE_LESS          * Cut the last  "X" amount of lines.
::  GL  = GET_LINE           * Delete all except "X" line.
::  GR  = GET_RANGE          * Delete all except "X" range of lines.

REM EXAMPLES:
::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the line 3                                                       ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN E 3 "Test.txt"                                            ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                        
:: Add a string to the beginning of line 3                                 ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN AL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                      
:: Add a string to the end of line 3.                                      ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN AR 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                       
:: Add a empty line at line 3.                                             ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt"                                            ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                       
:: Add a line with a word at line 3.                                       ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                           ::
::                                                                         ::    
:: Replace the line 3 with "Elektro H@cker".                               ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Replace the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in line 3.                      ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RS 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"                        ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Replace the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in all lines.                   ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RSA "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"                         ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the first 3 characters in all lines.                             ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN C+ 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the last 3 characters in all lines.                              ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN C- 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the first 3 lines.                                               ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN L+ 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the last 3 lines.                                                ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN L- 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete all except the line number 3.                                    ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN SL 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete all except the 3 to 9 range of lines.                            ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN SR 3 9 "Test.txt"                                         ::
::                                                                         ::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::

:TEXTMAN
(SET /A "A=0", "LINE=0", "TOTAL_LINES=0")  &  (CALL :%~1 %* || (ECHO Invalid parameter & Exit /B 1)) & (GOTO:EOF)
:AB
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE (if "%%B" EQU "" ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %~4%%B)>> "%~3.NEW"))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:AE
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %%B%~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:E
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B) >> "%~3.NEW"))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:I
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF     "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (IF NOT "%~4" EQU "" ((Echo %~4) >> "%~3.NEW") ELSE (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW"))" & (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW"))))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RL
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RS
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE (CALL SET "STRING=%%B" &&     (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~4=%~5%%)>> "%~3.NEW")))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RSA
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~2" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (CALL SET "STRING=%%B" && (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~2.NEW") ELSE ((CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~3=%~4%%)>>"%~2.NEW")))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~2") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C+
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~%~2%% >>      "%~3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C-
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~0,-%~2%% >>   "%~3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L+
(Call SET /A "A=%~2") && (Call TYPE "%~3" |@MORE +%%A%% > "%~3.NEW") && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L-
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES+=1")) & (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES-=%~2-1") & (For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" & Call echo "%%LINE%%"|@FIND "%%TOTAL_LINES%%" >NUL) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3" && GOTO:EOF) || (Echo %%B >> "%~3.NEW"))
:GL
(Call SET /A "A=%~2" && Call SET /A "A-=1") && (Call TYPE "%~3" |@MORE +%%A%% > "%temp%\getline.tmp") && (For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%temp%\getline.tmp" ^| find /n /v ""') DO ((if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)> "%~3.NEW"))) && ((CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF))) 
:GR
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~4" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "(IF "%%LINE%%" GEQ "%~2" IF "%%LINE%%" LEQ "%~3" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~4.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~4.NEW"))) && (IF "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~3" Exit /B 1)" || ((CALL :RENAMER "%~4") & (GOTO:EOF)))))
:RENAMER
(REN "%~1" "%~nx1.BAK") & (MOVE /Y "%~1.BAK" "%TEMP%\" >NUL) & (REN "%~1.NEW" "%~nx1") & (GOTO:EOF)
```

Comment: Command line in Windows

Comment: You can escape special characters with ^ (circumflex). For example like this `echo ^> > test.txt`. Here's a complete guide on batch escaping syntax http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: Please read this help article: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Point taken. Will try and rephrase the problem. I have a config.sys file that looks like the code below. I'm trying to automatically replace the 4th line: "From: abc <def@hotmail.com>" with input from another source.                                                                                                         `[global]
; Notes
; Notes
From: abc <def@hotmail.com>`

Answer (score 0):

The batch script you have found could be fixed to support your need, but the end result will still have significant limitations, and it will be fairly slow. Batch is not a good tool for manipulating files.

The solution is trivial with [JREPL.BAT, a regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward, without the need for any 3rd party .exe files.

Full documentation is available from the command line via `/?` (or `/??` if you want paged help).

I just released version 4.0 that makes it extremely easy to limit the search to specific line numbers.

```
call jrepl "^.*" "[global] ; Notes ; Notes From: abc <def@hotmail.com>" /inc 4 /f "file.txt" /o -
```

Prior to release 4, the solution required user supplied JScript in the `/JBEGLN` option:

```
call jrepl "^.*" "[global] ; Notes ; Notes From: abc <def@hotmail.com>" /jbegln "skip=(ln!=4)" /f "file.txt" /o -
```